# Wireless is not working on Lenovo ThinkPad X201 with CentOs 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, networkmanager, thinkpad

I am having trouble with wireless connection on my `Thinkpad X201` laptop. I installed `CentOs 6.5 Minimal`. The Wired (cable) internet works perfect. But wireless is not detected. I looked at following links but doesn't help me.

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Lenovo/Thinkpad-X200s

http://www.lapwik.com/lenovo_thinkpad_x201

by running `ifconfig -a` I cannot see the `wlan0`, although I setup wireless via `NetWork Manager` in `Gnome`.

Oh by the way, my laptop came with Windows7 on it which I completely wiped it out and installed Linux.

**-- UPDATE --**
Here is the output of `lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2193
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 215a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 215f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f2727800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2153
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f2500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f2525000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2163
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f2728000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 215e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f2520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0d, subordinate=0d, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2164
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=0c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: f0000000-f1ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2800000-00000000f28fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2164
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f2400000-f24fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2164
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2163
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f2728400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0e, subordinate=0e, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2165

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2166
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2168
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    I/O ports at 1860 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 1814 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1818 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 1810 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]
    Memory at f2727000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2167
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 23
    Memory at f2728800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 1880 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2190
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 19
    Memory at f2526000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel ips
    Kernel modules: intel_ips

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-26-c7-ff-ff-eb-a7-56
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

-- **UPDATE** --

Here is the output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   73530  2 
rfcomm                 74119  0 
sco                    18005  0 
bridge                 83689  0 
bnep                   16690  0 
l2cap                  55714  4 rfcomm,bnep
8021q                  25349  0 
garp                    7152  1 8021q
stp                     2218  2 bridge,garp
llc                     5546  3 bridge,garp,stp
ipt_REJECT              2351  2 
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9506  2 
nf_defrag_ipv4          1483  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_filter          2793  1 
ip_tables              17831  1 iptable_filter
ip6t_REJECT             4628  2 
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8337  2 
nf_defrag_ipv6         11156  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
xt_state                1492  4 
nf_conntrack           79758  3 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2889  1 
ip6_tables             18732  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  318183  21 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
uinput                  7992  0 
btusb                  16851  0 
bluetooth              99271  5 rfcomm,sco,bnep,l2cap,btusb
iTCO_wdt                7115  0 
iTCO_vendor_support     3056  1 iTCO_wdt
thinkpad_acpi          68622  0 
iwlwifi                92090  0 
cfg80211              619515  1 iwlwifi
rfkill                 19255  4 bluetooth,thinkpad_acpi,cfg80211
sg                     29350  0 
uvcvideo               62688  0 
videodev               75708  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32     7110  1 videodev
intel_ips              14598  0 
i2c_i801               11359  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     28922  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    39925  1 
snd_hda_intel          40562  2 
snd_hda_codec         179208  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep               6780  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                55727  0 
snd_seq_device          6500  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm                87409  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_timer              22443  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    70569  13 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm,snd_timer
soundcore               7958  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          8856  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lpc_ich                12803  0 
mfd_core                1895  1 lpc_ich
shpchp                 32778  0 
e1000e                267701  0 
ptp                     9614  1 e1000e
pps_core               11458  1 ptp
ext4                  374405  3 
jbd2                   93427  1 ext4
mbcache                 8193  1 ext4
sd_mod                 39069  3 
crc_t10dif              1541  1 sd_mod
ahci                   42247  2 
wmi                     6287  0 
i915                  624511  7 
drm_kms_helper         44321  1 i915
drm                   280012  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            5935  1 i915
i2c_core               31084  6 videodev,i2c_i801,i915,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit
video                  20674  1 i915
output                  2409  1 video
dm_mirror              14384  0 
dm_region_hash         12085  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                  9930  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 84337  11 dm_mirror,dm_log
```

Comment: Please check if the hardware switch for wireless (left side) is set to "enabled".

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -v`

Comment: @gnp I added the output of `lspci -v` to the post.

Comment: Please post the output of 'lsmod' and please answer the above question about hardware switch. Do you have a dedicated switch or a Fn+F# key combination to turn on/off wifi? Does anything happen when you press it?

Comment: Try `modprobe iwlwifi`. That chipset should work just fine.

Comment: @Bruno9779 I added the output of `lsmod`. Also confirmed that switch is open and `Fn + F5` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @gnp `modprobe iwlwifi` didn't work

Comment: Not sure if helps, but my bluetooth is working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the lspci -v output of yours, I assume "Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000" is your wireless adapter.

Could you please check if the firmware mentioned in the below page helps ?

http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm

> Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000  3.2+    iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz
>   2.6.30+   iwlwifi-1000-ucode-128.50.3.1.tgz

I see that iwlwifi module is already installed in your lsmod output. But not sure if it is of the right version. Also if your kernel is older than 2.6.30, i guess it might not work.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you so much dude. I copy/paste the firmware as said in the link you provided and restarted my system and it worked perfect.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue is resolved !